# Angular 11 build issue during deployment

Tags: angular

I have issue during deployment of Angular app to Digital Ocean. The build is failing (Throwing Build failed (145)) almost every time. If I remove node_modules folder sometimes it is working but not always. Currently I'm not able to deploy my code. I'm using Angular 11 together with Universal.

Below is the error log I'm getting, any idea where should I start digging to resolve it ?

Error log from Digitial Ocean console:

```
tg-front | 19:18:57 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
tg-front | 19:18:57 
tg-front | 19:18:57 Error: ./src/styles.css
tg-front | 19:18:57 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract- 
plugin/dist/loader.js):
tg-front | 19:18:57 ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css- 
loader/dist/cjs.js):
tg-front | 19:18:57 Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-import-parser requires PostCSS 8.
tg-front | 19:18:57 Migration guide for end-users:
tg-front | 19:18:57 https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
tg-front | 19:18:57     at Processor.normalize (/workspace/node_modules/css- 
loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:167:15)
tg-front | 19:18:57     at new Processor (/workspace/node_modules/css- 
loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:56:25)
tg-front | 19:18:57     at postcss (/workspace/node_modules/css- 
loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:55:10)
tg-front | 19:18:57     at Object.loader (/workspace/node_modules/css- 
loader/dist/index.js:140:41)
tg-front | 19:18:57     at /workspace/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build- 
angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "tg-front",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node dist/tg-front/server/main.js",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"dev:ssr": "ng run tg-front:serve-ssr",
"start:ssr": "node dist/tg-front/server/main.js",
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run tg-front:server:production",
"prerender": "ng run tg-front:prerender"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/common": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/core": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
"@angular/forms": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/material": "^11.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/router": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/service-worker": "^11.2.3",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.2.0",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"express": "^4.15.2",
"rxjs": "^6.6.6",
"sitemap": "^6.4.0",
"tslib": "^2.1.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.2",
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.3",
"@nguniversal/builders": "^11.2.0",
"@types/express": "^4.17.11",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.20.4",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~5.2.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "^4.0.5",
"webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding additional script in the build process with following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clear --force && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You may manually delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file then execute the following command before you build your Angular app:

```
npm install
```

It should re-generate the `package-lock.json` file and of course `node_modules` folder. Hope that it might work for you!